# Detecting cyclic behaviour in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am doing yet another [projecteuler](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=74) question in Haskell, where I must find if the sum of the factorials of each digit in a number is equal to the original number. If not repeat the process until the original number is reached. The next part is to find the number of starting numbers below 1 million that have 60 non-repeating units. I got this far:

```
prob74 = length [ x | x <- [1..999999], 60 == ((length $ chain74 x)-1)]

factorial n = product [1..n]

factC x = sum $ map factorial (decToList x)

chain74 x  | x == 0 = []
           | x == 1 = [1]
           | x /= factC x = x : chain74 (factC x)
```

But what I don't know how to do is to get it to stop once the value for `x` has become cyclic. How would I go about stopping `chain74` when it gets back to the original number?

Comment: As an aside, you can write `factC` in a more elegant way like this: `factC = sum . map factorial . decToList`. And `chain74` for the values `0` and `1` are better written using pattern matching, i.e. `chain74 0 = []` etc.

Comment: Note that the chain doesn't need to go back to the original number, the cycle can also start "in the middle", like in `78 → 45360 → 871 → 45361 → 871 → 45361 → 871 → ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you walk through the list that might contain a cycle your function needs to keep track of the already seen elements to be able to check for repetitions. Every new element is compared against the already seen elements. If the new element has already been seen, the cycle is complete, if it hasn't been seen the next element is inspected.

So this calculates the length of the non-cyclic part of a list:

```
uniqlength :: (Eq a) => [a] -> Int
uniqlength l = uniqlength_ l []
   where uniqlength_ [] ls = length ls
         uniqlength_ (x:xs) ls
            | x `elem` ls = length ls
            | otherwise   = uniqlength_ xs (x:ls)
```

(Performance might be better when using a set instead of a list, but I haven't tried that.)

Comment: I know this is not the best solution in terms of speed/memory use, but I don't think it gets simpler than this.

Answer (score 1):

What about passing another argument (y for example) to the chain74 in the list comprehension.

Morning fail so EDIT:

```
[.. ((length $ chain74 x x False)-1)]



chain74 x y not_first  | x == y && not_first = replace_with_stop_value_:-)
                       | x == 0 = []
                       | x == 1 = [1]
                       | x == 2 = [2]
                       | x /= factC x = x : chain74 (factC x) y True
```

Comment: This is all well and good. But it seems will always equal y at the start. Also, GHCi didn't like stop_value. What do I do there to make it happy?

Comment: Buy it chocolate, if I were GHCi I would like chocolate

Comment: Corrected that poor answer. Chocolate is good but rather replace that with an empty list or so :)

Comment: ghci still doesn't like this. It's all: non exhaustive patterns in function chain74

Comment: That is a runtime error; add a pattern that matches what you're passing in.

Comment: added problematic one - (chain74 2 2 False)

Answer (score 1):

I implemented a cycle-detection algorithm in Haskell on my blog. It should work for you, but there might be a more clever approach for this particular problem:

http://coder.bsimmons.name/blog/2009/04/cycle-detection/

Just change the return type from String to Bool.

**EDIT:** Here is a modified version of the algorithm I posted about:

```
cycling :: (Show a, Eq a) => Int -> [a] -> Bool
cycling k []     = False --not cycling
cycling k (a:as) = find 0 a 1 2 as
    where find _ _ c _  [] = False
          find i x c p (x':xs) 
            | c >  k    =  False  -- no cycles after k elements
            | x == x'   =  True   -- found a cycle 
            | c == p    = find c x' (c+1) (p*2) xs 
            | otherwise = find i x  (c+1) p xs
```

You can remove the 'k' if you know your list will either cycle or terminate soon.

**EDIT2:** You could change the following function to look something like:

```
prob74 = length [ x | x <- [1..999999], let chain = chain74 x, not$ cycling 999 chain, 60 == ((length chain)-1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Quite a fun problem. I've come up with a corecursive function that returns the list of the "factorial chains" for every number, stopping as soon as they would repeat themselves:

```
chains = [] : let f x = x : takeWhile (x /=) (chains !! factC x) in (map f [1..])
```

Giving:

```
take 4 chains == [[],[1],[2],[3,6,720,5043,151,122,5,120,4,24,26,722,5044,169,363601,1454]]

map head $ filter ((== 60) . length) (take 10000 chains) 
is 
[1479,1497,1749,1794,1947,1974,4079,4097,4179,4197,4709,4719,4790,4791,4907,4917
,4970,4971,7049,7094,7149,7194,7409,7419,7490,7491,7904,7914,7940,7941,9047,9074
,9147,9174,9407,9417,9470,9471,9704,9714,9740,9741]
```

It works by calculating the "factC" of its position in the list, then references that position in itself. This would generate an infinite list of infinite lists (using lazy evaluation), but using takeWhile the inner lists only continue until the element occurs again or the list ends (meaning a deeper element in the corecursion has repeated itself).

If you just want to remove cycles from a list you can use:

```
decycle :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]
decycle = dc []
    where
        dc _ [] = []
        dc xh (x : xs) = if elem x xh then [] else x : dc (x : xh) xs

decycle [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 2] == [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Feel free to explain how it finds the cycle

Comment: Added a small explanation but it's not particularly clear so if you have any follow on questions I'll try to answer them

Comment: Upon running this after compilation I got the error:
Prelude.(!!): index too large

Comment: Very strange if this is the case, since the list is infinitely long the index can never be too large. Also I've noticed my solution makes chains that don't include the first element so I've fixed that.